# Как грамотно организовывать неопределенное количество pollfd структур?

Tags: linux, c, tcp

Есть tcp socket сервер, он использует конечнный автомат и ожидает запросы на чтение/подключение/запись через функцию ppoll.

Как грамотно организовать массив pollfd структур. Допустим, сразу pollfd[10000] или использовать realloc при новом подключении (но это ведь затратно). При первом варианте максимум 10000 соединений, а вдруг нужно больше? Какой есть ещё способ организовать большое количество одновременных соединений?

Comment: Делайте аналогично `std::vector` - резервируйте больше памяти, чем нужно и храните количество хранимых элементов отдельно от емкости.

Comment: Вместе с массивом (вызываете  realloс + приращение на некоторую величину если нет места для новых) храните 1) сколько выделено 2) максимальный занятый элемент. Когда сокет закрываете, уплотняйте массив. Новые добавляете в конец. Если места уже нет, вызываете realloc